# Query for getting attributes value in simple db

Tags: amazon-simpledb

i am using simple db. in my simple db have **"device.OS"** attribute. i want that same attibute values for "device.OS". please help for this problem.

NOte:
 i can try normal attribute value i can possible to get the value.
but if **"."** is there in attribute name not possible to get the values.
it shows "syntax error"

Thanks,
senthil

Answer (score 3):

When using SELECT in SimpleDB there are times when the attribute name itself must be quoted. If the name (attribute name or domain name) contains any characters other than letters, numbers, underscore and dollar-sign then you must quote it.

When quoting names in a SimpleDB SELECT, the back-tic character (`) is used (as opposed to quoting *values* which allows single quote or double quote character)

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE `device.OS` = 'Linux'
```

[SimpleDB SELECT Quoting Rules](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuotingRulesSelect.html)